# How to escape special characters in a KQL query?

Tags: 2013, search, kql

In a list I have a column with these values:

```
MyField
-------
foo.A
foo.B
foo.*
```

I want to search for these values. I've plumbed all managed properties and crawled content.

- If I search `myfield:"foo."`, all results are returned ==> **Expected**
- If I search `myfield:"foo.A"`, results with the `foo.A` are returned.==> **Expected**
- If I search `myfield:"foo.*"`, both `foo.A` and `foo.B` are returned, but not `foo.*` ==> ***not* Expected**. I need to get *only* `foo.*`

How to search for literal `*`?

I also tried : `myfield:"foo.\*"`, `myfield:"\foo.*"`, `myfield:{"foo.*"}`, but none worked.

Documentation does not mention any way to escape special characters.

Comment: just give a try to this myfield:"foo.'*'"

Comment: Or try myfield:"foo.%2A", I have replaced \"*\" with its encoding value, since \"*\" (asterisk) is a wild card keyword in KQL, is will search for all text starting foo. let me knw if it works. Havent tried this scenario yet

Answer (score 1):

KQL is also used when doing compliance searches in Microsoft Exchange.

I was able to use `$ to escape characters when doing searches in Exchange

```
"foo`$*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with just ` in Kibana logs with KQL syntax